# sed and special characters inside a variable (macOS Monterey)

Tags: shell, sed, zsh, macos-monterey

I'm new to shell scripting and Terminal usage.
I have the follow line of code in a zsh script, where the `PATH_VAR` is always an absolute folder path that I have to insert:

```
#!/bin/zsh
...
read PATH_VAR
sed -i "" "s/\"PATH_VAR=.*\"/\"PATH_VAR=$PATH_VAR\"/" file.txt
...
```

The idea is to replace the variable value on a text file, where the string I want to replace is ("" included):

```
"PATH_VAR=/Path/to/folder"
```

I set the variable as, for example, `/Path/to/folder`; the follow line pops out:

```
sed: line: "s/\"PATH_VAR=.*\"/\"P ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'P'
```

I understand that this is due to the `/` that gets interpreted differently by `sed`; in fact when I run:

```
sed -i "" "s/\"PATH_VAR=.*\"/\"PATH_VAR=\/Path\/to\/folder\"/" file.txt
```

everything goes smoothly and the string gets replaced.
I want to know if there's a workaround. Since the `PATH_VAR` is always an absolute path, I thought about recoursively adding the \ before every / that is found in the `PATH_VAR` variable. Is this possible with `sed`?

Comment: If you need to substitute arbitrary strings, sed isn't the ideal tool for the job. See [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), which includes alternatives using awk or perl instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of struggling to escape those slashes, you may want to pick another separator for sed's `s` command. E.g. `sed 's@....@...@'` or `sed 's#...#...#'`

But of course, **this only works if the picked separator doesn't appear in your pattern/replacement.**

Comment: I didn't know about it, thank you so much! I used an appropriate character. Probably better to use ```pearl``` or ```awk``` next time.

Comment: @comws no problem. Good to know your problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody ever remembers that `sed` has commands besides `s`. It also has, for example, `c` to **c**hange a matching line:

```bash
sed -i '' '/"PATH_VAR=.*"/c\
"PATH_VAR='"$PATH_VAR"'"
' file.txt
```

Your variable just needs to not have any newlines in it with this approach.

Comment: So I can omit the ```/``` by using a newline?

Comment: If you want to replace it with multiple lines, each but the las has to end in a backslash (Which is not inserted but tells sed the text continues on the next line)